# Regex Problem in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following regex to parse a date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format:

`^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$`

I've checked it on strfriend and it all looks ok. However, when testing for it in PHP with `preg_match` it doesn't recognize it:

```
if(!preg_match("/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$/",trim($_POST['dob']))){
  $error .= "You must enter a valid date of birth.";
}
```

This happens with input such as `29/10/1987` and `01-01-2001`, and I'm not sure why it doesn't work!

I also get the following warning:

`Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '.' in /home/queensba/public_html/workers/apply.php on line 18`

which I'm not sure how to interpret.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use '/' in within your regex, you may not start/end the regular expression with it. Just replace it with '#' for example.

```
if(!preg_match("#^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$#",trim($_POST['dob']))){
  $error .= "You must enter a valid date of birth.";
}
```

(BTW, [Modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) would come after the final [delimiter](http://www.php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters) '#'. So the warning appeared because PHP thought the regex would end after the second '/'.)

Comment: How does it get past `"\d"` as its unknown escape sequence?

Comment: `"\\d"` should work, too. Like below `\/`, `\d` doesn't exist as php escape sequence, so it it stays esacped for the regex engine.

Answer (score 2):

The `/` inside your regex trip up PHP because it thinks they are your regex delimiters.

Try

```
if(!preg_match("#^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$#",trim($_POST['dob']))){
  $error .= "You must enter a valid date of birth.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using /.../ as the pattern delimiter you need to escape all other instances of / like \/  alternative is to use a different delimiter like ~

Comment: umm..why not? / isn't a special escape char, so php won't parse it as anything other than a literal \/

Comment: @Crayon Violent, I thought php was like Perl in string interpolation. `\"` isin't special, what about `"\$variable"`? I mean if you say there is no interpolation other than standard control codes i believe you.

Comment: yep, that's pretty much it with php. It will parse for instance "\n" as a newline (standard control codes) but other than that, nope.  But it does have some interpolation. You can do "$variable" and it will use the value of $variable.

Comment: @Crayon Violet amazing. So given $var = "VAR"; $str = "this\"\$var"; would parse as `this\"\VAR`. In Perl, it parses as `this"$var`

Comment: not quite. Since you escape the $ it treats it as a literal $ instead of a sign to parse a variable. So what you will actually get is this"$var

Comment: but if you $str = "this\"$var"; you will get this"VAR

Answer (score 1):

Don't use double quotes for strings, they're for templates.
If you have '/' in your pattern, you cannot begin and end it with the same character, do it with "%","#" or any other characters...
If you have unicode string, you have to use the "u" flag.

Comment: Agree, with the note that literal ' and \ have to be escaped.